# How to access User Information Columns in a Workflow

Tags: lookup-column, designer-workflow, user

I need to access a custom column of User Information List in a work flow.
I've create a new column named MyCol in User Information List and now in a workflow I want to access to in when I lookup Workflow context current user but I can't see my column.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom column should appear in the "Current Item" or the "User Information List" selection in the "Field to Retreive" dialog, not the Workflow context current user.

[image]